# Access to a matrix with indexes from a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix a(16x3) and a vector b(16x1). b shows how many of the values in the matrix a are valid per row.

```
a = magic(3)

a =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

b = [1;3;2]

b =

     1
     3
     2
```

What I'm trying to do is setting the invalid values to NaN:

```
a(:,b+1:end)=NaN
```

Result is:

```
a =

     8   NaN   NaN
     3   NaN   NaN
     4   NaN   NaN
```

But what I would have expected is:

a =

```
 8   NaN   NaN
 3     5     7
 4     9   NaN
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You cannot acces the matrix like that. a( n,m) expects m and n to be  values or arrays, but not matrices.

Comment: You may do it in a loop. is it okey for you?

Comment: For loop is clear to me, but I was trying to do it with a matrix operation.

Comment: Did any of the solutions listed here work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect setup for **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** with `@gt` to create a logical mask of those elements and then **[logically index](http://www.mathworks.in/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)** into `a` to set them as `NaNs` -

```
a(bsxfun(@gt,1:size(a,2),b(:))) = NaN
```

Sample run for a generic `m x n` case -

```
a =
     2     9     7     2     9
     5     7     2     9     5
     7     5     1     3     1
     8     1     6     2     2
b =
     1
     4
     3
     2
a =
     2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     5     7     2     9   NaN
     7     5     1   NaN   NaN
     8     1   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Here, the `logical mask` was -

```
>> bsxfun(@gt,1:size(a,2),b(:))
ans =
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1
```

So, the `1s` were used to select the elements that were **`to be`** set as `NaNs` and rest of the elements were **`not to be`** touched or changed.

You can also use `a(~bsxfun(@le,1:size(a,2),b(:))) = NaN` for the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I could come up with an idea,

```
 a = magic(3);
 b = [1;3;2];
```

the code:

```
 a (repmat(b,[1 , 3]) < repmat(1 : 3 , [3 , 1])) = NaN
```

gives;

```
 a =

 8   NaN   NaN
 3     5     7
 4     9   NaN
```

For your matrix sizes it would be,

```
 a = randi(9,[16 3]); 
 b = randi([0 3],[16 1]);
```

the code:

```
 a (repmat(b,[1 , 3]) < repmat(1 : 3 , [16 , 1])) = NaN
```