# Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT

Tags: performance, matlab, benchmarking, vectorization, bsxfun

Few questions were asked before on comparisons between **`bsxfun`** and **`repmat`** for performance.

- One of them was: [**`Matlab - bsxfun no longer faster than repmat?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28722723/3293881). This one tried to investigate performance comparisons between `repmat` and `bsxfun`, specific to performing subtraction of an input array's mean along the columns from the input array itself and as such would explore only the `@minus` part of `bsxfun` against its `repmat` equivalent.
- Another was : [**`In Matlab, when is it optimal to use bsxfun?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12951453/3293881). That one tried to do the same operation of subtraction by the mean along columns and didn't expand onto other built-in operations either.

With this post, I am trying to investigate the performance numbers between **`bsxfun`** and **`repmat`** to cover all the **`bsxfun`** built-ins to sort of give it a wider perspective as both of these present good vectorized solutions.

Specifically, my questions with this post are:

1. How do the various built-in operations with **`bsxfun`** perform against **`repmat`** equivalents? **`bsxfun`** supports floating point operations like `@plus`, `@minus`, `@times`, etc. and also relational and logical operations like `@ge`, `@and`, etc. So, are there specific built-ins that would give me noticeable speedups with **`bsxfun`** than using their **`repmat`** equivalents?
2. Loren in her [**`blog post`**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/) has benchmarked **`repmat`** against **`bsxfun`** with timing `@() A - repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1)` against `@() bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A))` respectively. If I need to cover benchmarking for all the built-ins, can I use some other comparison model that would work with floating point, relational and logical operations?

Answer (score 43):

### Introduction

The debate on whether `bsxfun` is better than `repmat` or vice versa has been going on like forever. In this post, we would try to compare how the different built-ins that ship with MATLAB fight it out against `repmat` equivalents in terms of their runtime performances and hopefully draw some meaningful conclusions out of them.

### Getting to know BSXFUN built-ins

If the official documentation is pulled out from the MATLAB environment or through the [Mathworks website](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), one can see the complete list of built-in functions supported by `bsxfun`. That list has functions for floating point, relational and logical operations.

On `MATLAB 2015A`, the supported element-wise floating point operations are :

- @plus (summation)
- @minus (subtraction)
- @times (multiplication)
- @rdivide (right-divide)
- @ldivide (left-divide)
- @pow (power)
- @rem (remainder)
- @mod (modulus)
- @atan2 (four quadrant inverse tangent)
- @atan2d (four quadrant inverse tangent in degrees)
- @hypot (square root of sum of squares).

The second set consists of element-wise relational operations and those are :

- @eq (equal)
- @ne (not-equal)
- @lt (less-than)
- @le (less-than or equal)
- @gt (greater-than)
- @ge (greater-than or equal).

The third and final set comprises of logical operations as listed here :

- @and (logical and)
- @or (logical or)
- @xor (logical xor).

Please note that we have excluded two built-ins `@max (maximum)` and `@min (minimum)` from our comparison tests, as there could be many ways one can implement their `repmat` equivalents.

### Comparison Model

To truly compare the performances between `repmat` and `bsxfun`, we need to make sure that the timings only need to cover the operations intended. Thus, something like `bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A))` won't be ideal, as it has to calculate `mean(A)` inside that `bsxfun` call, however insignificant that timing might be. Instead, we can use another input `B` of the same size as `mean(A)`.

Thus, we can use: `A = rand(m,n)` & `B = rand(1,n)`, where `m` and `n` are the size parameters which we could vary and study the performances based upon them. This is exactly done in our benchmarking tests listed in the next section.

The `repmat` and `bsxfun` versions to operate on those inputs would look something like these -

```
REPMAT: A + repmat(B,size(A,1),1)
BSXFUN: bsxfun(@plus,A,B)
```

### Benchmarking

Finally, we are at the crux of this post to watch these two guys fight it out. We have segregated the benchmarking into three sets, one for the floating point operations, another for the relational and the third one for the logical operations. We have extended the comparison model as discussed earlier to all these operations.

**Set1: Floating point operations**

Here's the first set of benchmarking code for floating point operations with `repmat` and `bsxfun` -

```
datasizes = [ 100 100; 100 1000; 100 10000; 100 100000;
              1000 100; 1000 1000; 1000 10000;
              10000 100; 10000 1000; 10000 10000;
              100000 100; 100000 1000];

num_funcs = 11;
tsec_rep = NaN(size(datasizes,1),num_funcs);
tsec_bsx = NaN(size(datasizes,1),num_funcs);
for iter = 1:size(datasizes,1)
    m = datasizes(iter,1);
    n = datasizes(iter,2);
    A = rand(m,n);
    B = rand(1,n);

    fcns_rep= {@() A + repmat(B,size(A,1),1),@() A - repmat(B,size(A,1),1),...
        @() A .* repmat(B,size(A,1),1), @() A ./ repmat(B,size(A,1),1),...
        @() A.\repmat(B,size(A,1),1), @() A .^ repmat(B,size(A,1),1),...
        @() rem(A ,repmat(B,size(A,1),1)), @() mod(A,repmat(B,size(A,1),1)),...
        @() atan2(A,repmat(B,size(A,1),1)),@() atan2d(A,repmat(B,size(A,1),1)),...
        @() hypot( A , repmat(B,size(A,1),1) )};

    fcns_bsx = {@() bsxfun(@plus,A,B), @() bsxfun(@minus,A,B), ...
        @() bsxfun(@times,A,B),@() bsxfun(@rdivide,A,B),...
        @() bsxfun(@ldivide,A,B), @() bsxfun(@power,A,B), ...
        @() bsxfun(@rem,A,B), @() bsxfun(@mod,A,B), @() bsxfun(@atan2,A,B),...
        @() bsxfun(@atan2d,A,B), @() bsxfun(@hypot,A,B)};

    for k1 = 1:numel(fcns_bsx)
        tsec_rep(iter,k1) = timeit(fcns_rep{k1});
        tsec_bsx(iter,k1) = timeit(fcns_bsx{k1});
    end
end
speedups = tsec_rep./tsec_bsx;
```

**Set2: Relational operations**

The benchmarking code to time relational operations would replace `fcns_rep`  and  `fcns_bsx` from the earlier benchmarking code with these counterparts -

```
fcns_rep = {
    @() A == repmat(B,size(A,1),1), @() A ~= repmat(B,size(A,1),1),...
    @() A < repmat(B,size(A,1),1), @() A <= repmat(B,size(A,1),1), ...
    @() A > repmat(B,size(A,1),1), @() A >= repmat(B,size(A,1),1)};

fcns_bsx = {
    @() bsxfun(@eq,A,B), @() bsxfun(@ne,A,B), @() bsxfun(@lt,A,B),...
    @() bsxfun(@le,A,B), @() bsxfun(@gt,A,B), @() bsxfun(@ge,A,B)};
```

**Set3: Logical operations**

The final set of benchmarking codes would use the logical operations as listed here -

```
fcns_rep = {
    @() A & repmat(B,size(A,1),1), @() A | repmat(B,size(A,1),1), ...
    @() xor(A,repmat(B,size(A,1),1))};

fcns_bsx = {
    @() bsxfun(@and,A,B), @() bsxfun(@or,A,B), @() bsxfun(@xor,A,B)};
```

Please note that for this specific set, the input data, A and B needed were logical arrays. So, we had to do these edits in the earlier benchmarking code to create logical arrays  -

```
A = rand(m,n)>0.5;
B = rand(1,n)>0.5;
```

### Runtimes and Observations

The benchmarking codes were run on this system configuration:

```
MATLAB Version: 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
RAM: 16GB
CPU Model: Intel® Core i7-4790K @4.00GHz
```

The speedups thus obtained with `bsxfun` over `repmat` after running the benchmark tests were plotted for the three sets as shown next.

**A. Floating point operations:**

[image]

Few observations could be drawn from the speedup plot:

- The notably two good speedups cases with `bsxfun` are for `atan2` and `atan2d`.
- Next in that list are right and left divide operations that boosts performs with `30% - 50%` over the `repmat` equivalent codes.
- Going further down in that list are the remaining `7` operations whose speedups seem very close to unity and thus need a closer inspection. The speedup plot could be narrowed down to just those `7` operations as shown next -

[image]

Based on the above plot, one could see that barring one-off cases with `@hypot` and `@mod`, `bsxfun` still performs roughly 10% better than  `repmat` for these `7` operations.

**B. Relational operations:**

This is the second set of benchmarking for the next 6 built-in relational operations supported by `bsxfun`.

[image]

Looking at the speedup plot above, neglecting the starting case that had comparable runtimes between `bsxfun` and `repmat`, one can easily see `bsxfun` winning for these relational operations. With speedups touching **`10x`**, `bsxfun` would  always be preferable for these cases.

**C. Logical operations:**

This is the third set of benchmarking for the remaining 3 built-in logical operations supported by `bsxfun`.

[image]

Neglecting the one-off comparable runtime case for `@xor` at the start, `bsxfun` seems to have an upper hand for this set of logical operations too.

### Conclusions

1. When working with relational and logical operations, `repmat` could easily be forgotten in favor of `bsxfun`. For rest of the cases, one can still persist with `bsxfun` if one off cases with `5 - 7%` lesser performance is tolerable.
2. Seeing the kind of huge performance boost when using relational and logical operations with `bsxfun`, one can think about using `bsxfun` to work on data with **`ragged patterns`**, something like cell arrays for performance benefits. I like to call these solution cases as ones using **`bsxfun`'s masking capability**. This basically means that we create logical arrays, i.e. masks with `bsxfun`, which can be used to exchange data between cell arrays and numeric arrays. One of the advantages to have workable data in numeric arrays is that vectorized methods could be used to process them. Again, since `bsxfun` is a good tool for vectorization, you may find yourself using it once more working down on the same problem, so there are more reasons to get to know `bsxfun`. Few solution cases where I was able to explore such methods are linked here for the benefit of the readers:
   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851816/3293881), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26712733/3293881),
   [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26782789/3293881), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152767/3293881),
   [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28027094/3293881).

### Future work

The present work focused on replicating data along one dimension with `repmat`. Now, `repmat` can replicate along multiple dimensions and so do `bsxfun` with its expansions being equivalent to replications. As such, it would be interesting to perform similar tests on replications and expansions onto multiple dimensions with these two functions.