# Create strings from the indices of two vectors in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two vectors `a` and `b` as an example:

`a = [1 2 3 4];`
`b = [5 6 7 8];`

I want to create strings from the indices of `a` and `b`:

```
c1 = a(1):b(1) = [1 2 3 4 5];
c2 = a(2):b(2) = [2 3 4 5 6];
c3 = a(3):b(3) = [3 4 5 6 7];
c4 = a(4):b(4) = [4 5 6 7 8];
```

Then I want to concatenate the obtained strings:

`C = cat(2, c1, c2, c3, c4) = [1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8];`

I would like a general solution to help me automatize this algorithm.

Comment: Wouldn't `a(2):b(2) = [3 4 5 6]`? Also do you really want strings and not just vectors of doubles?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I made an edit. I changed something at first, and I forgot to update the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

This should do the trick without using a loop:

```
>> a = [1 3 4 5];
>> b = [5 6 7 8];
>> resultstr = num2str(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) x:y,a,b,'UniformOutput',false)))

resultstr =

1  2  3  4  5  3  4  5  6  4  5  6  7  5  6  7  8
```

---

**Performance**

I tried to do a quick comparison between this method, [Luis Mendo's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32142523/3871918) and the `for` loop (see e.g. [A. Visser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139701/3871918)). I created two arrays with pseudo-random numbers from 1 to 50 and 501 to 1000 and timed the calculation for array sizes from 1 to 300, disregarding the string conversion.

[image: Performance comparison]

Luis Mendo's anwer is the clear winner, in terms of time complexity `arrayfun` seems to be on par with `bsxfun`. The `for` loop fares much worse, except for very small array sizes, but I'm not sure the timing can be trusted there.

The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d630d108a5c684fff264). I'd be very happy to get some feedback, I'm a bit unsure about those measurements.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for such an approach.

Comment: Just so you know, `arrayfun` is actually a for-loop in disguise even though it fits on one line But nicely done anyway!

Comment: Benoit_11: The performance difference however is quite drastic, the `for` loop is ~20-30 times slower on my machine, probably because the resulting array can't be preallocated – I'm not a MATLAB performance expert though...

Comment: @dasdingonesin. Generally, it is better to use [`timeit`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) rather than `tic/toc` for accurate timing and benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for the effort to do the timing! As Hoki says, `timeit` is more accurate for running time measurements

Answer (score 5):

This can be done without loops (be they `for`, `arrayfun` or `cellfun`) using [`bsxfun`'s masking capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat). This works also if the "strings" have different lengths, as in the following example.

```
a = [1 2 3];
b = [3 5 6];
m = (0:max(b-a)).'; %'
C = bsxfun(@plus, a, m);
mask = bsxfun(@le, m, b-a);
C = C(mask).';
```

The result in this example is:

```
C =
     1     2     3     2     3     4     5     3     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
A = [1:5; 5:8];, C = [];
for i = A, C = [C i(1):i(2)]; end
Cstr = num2str(C);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
a = [1 3 4 5]; b = [5 6 7 8];
c =[];
for i =1:length(a)
    c = [c [a(i):b(i)]];
end
num2str(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't assign variables as `C1`, `C2`, `C3` etc, use cells for that.

I'd use a `for`-loop for this, though there probably is a better alternative.

```
a = [1 3 4 5]; b = [5 6 7 8];
C = [];
for ii = 1:length(a)
    tmp = a(ii):b(ii);
    C = [C tmp];
end
```

This way `tmp` stores your separate arrays, then the following line adds it to the pre-existing array `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
a = [1 2 3 4]; b = [5 6 7 8];

A=fliplr(gallery('circul',fliplr([a,b])));
B=A(1:numel(a)+1,1:numel(a));
C=num2str(B(:).')
```