# setdiff row by row without using loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Let's say we have two matrices

```
A = [1,2,3;
     2,4,5;
     8,3,5]
B=  [2,3;
     4,5;
     8,5]
```

How do I perform `sediff` for each row in A and B respectively without using loops or cellfun, in other words performing `setdiff(A(i,:),B(i,:))` for all `i`. For this example I want to get

```
[1;
 2;
 3]
```

I am trying to do this for two very big matrices for my fluid simulator, thus I can't compromise on performance.

> UPDATE:

you can assume that the second dimension (number of columns) of the answer will be fixed e.g. the answer will always be some n by m matrix and not some ragged array of different column sizes.

> Another Example:

In my case A and B are m by 3 and m by 2 respectively and the answer should be m by 1. A solution for this case will suffice, but a general solution for matrices of size m by n1, m by n2 with answer of m by n3  will be very interesting. another example is

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5;
     8,4,7,9,6]
B = [2,3;
     4,9]
```

And the answer is

```
C = [1,4,5;
     8,7,6]
```

Comment: Number of elements for each such run in a row might have different number of elements unless you have some constraints that puts the number of such *setdfiffed* elements to be the same for each row run. So, how do you plan to store such ragged arrays?

Comment: I agree with Divakar, cellfun would be the way to go, as your output is presumbly a cell-array.

Comment: I will fix my question. in my case the second dimension of the answer is guaranteed to be fixed for all rows. in any other case you are both correct.

Comment: Will the second dimension always be one? Can you please post another example where it isn't? And does it contain zeros?

Comment: the second dimension won't contain zeros because I am working on matrices of indices (starting from 1 to m).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1** Using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
mask = all(bsxfun(@ne,A,permute(B,[1 3 2])),3);
At = A.'; %//'
out = reshape(At(mask.'),[],size(A,1)).'
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2     3     4     5
     8     4     7     9     6
>> B
B =
     2     3
     4     9
>> mask = all(bsxfun(@ne,A,permute(B,[1 3 2])),3);
>> At = A.'; %//'
>> out = reshape(At(mask.'),[],size(A,1)).'
out =
     1     4     5
     8     7     6
```

---

**Approach #2** Using [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) -

```
sAB = sort([A B],2)
dsAB = diff(sAB,[],2)~=0

mask1 = [true(size(A,1),1) dsAB]
mask2 = [dsAB true(size(A,1),1)]

mask = mask1 & mask2
sABt = sAB.'

out = reshape(sABt(mask.'),[],size(A,1)).'
```

Comment: is bsxfun faster then a loop? because cellfun for example is only faster when using predefined functions with it.

Comment: @DontCareBear It would depend a lot on the available system RAM and the dimensions of inputs involved. Best way would be to test out. But since we are dealing with relational operators, I would think it would be performance boost for sure, unless your inputs stretch bsxfun to the limits.

Comment: is their any gain using A.' instead of A' (except syntactically)?

Comment: @DontCareBear Nope, it's just to make sure we are transposing and not getting complex conjugates.

Comment: @DontCareBear See [`Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29719681/3293881) for some benchmarks on bsxfun relational operators.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to do it with only matrix operation? assuming unique elements per row.

Comment: @DontCareBear Let me ask you - Do they always have unique elements per row?

Comment: yes you can definitely assume that. in my code the first matrix is a matrix of face endpoint indices (of a 2d mesh) and the second matrix is edge endpoint indices.

Comment: @DontCareBear Also, does the order of elements in each row in the expected output matter?

Comment: @DontCareBear Check out the new added approach?

Comment: The first one is faster. Nevertheless thank you very much. the two answers helped me a lot. Amazing answers!

Comment: @DontCareBear never forget *bsxfun is always the fastest!* ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk Not suprised for sure I bet! ;)

Comment: @DontCareBear Just curious, about the speedups you are getting with these solutions over your original setdiff based approach?

Comment: my first method was just using for loop with setdiff which can't be good :P I run each of the methods with tic toc and that's what I got:
Elapsed time is 3.137423 seconds. lousy for loop
Elapsed time is 0.002065 seconds. your first method
Elapsed time is 0.002508 seconds. your second method

Comment: @DontCareBear Hmm, nice!! Thanks for getting those numbers! Well, bsxfun FTW! ;)