# Matlab: create matrix whose rows are identical vector. Use repmat() or multiply by ones()

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to create a matrix from a vector by concatenating the vector onto itself n times. So if my vector is `mx1`, then my matrix will be `mxn` and each column of the matrix will be equal to the vector.

Which of the following is the best/correct way, or maybe there is a better way I do not know?

```
matrix = repmat(vector, 1, n);
matrix = vector * ones(1, n);
```

Thanks

Comment: What about `matrix = bsxfun(@times , vector , ones(1,n) )` ... it's probably even faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some **benchmarking** using [`timeit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) with **different vector sizes** and **repetition factors**. The results to be shown are for Matlab R2015b on Windows.

First define a function for each of the considered approaches:

```
%// repmat approach
function matrix = f_repmat(vector, n)
matrix = repmat(vector, 1, n);

%// multiply approach
function matrix = f_multiply(vector, n)
matrix = vector * ones(1, n);

%// indexing approach
function matrix = f_indexing(vector,n)
matrix = vector(:,ones(1,n));
```

Then generate vectors of different size, and use different repetition factors:

```
M = round(logspace(2,4,15)); %// vector sizes
N = round(logspace(2,3,15)); %// repetition factors
time_repmat   = NaN(numel(M), numel(N)); %// preallocate results
time_multiply = NaN(numel(M), numel(N));
time_indexing = NaN(numel(M), numel(N));
for ind_m = 1:numel(M);
    for ind_n = 1:numel(N);
        vector = (1:M(ind_m)).';
        n = N(ind_n);
        time_repmat(ind_m, ind_n)   = timeit(@() f_repmat(vector, n)); %// measure time
        time_multiply(ind_m, ind_n) = timeit(@() f_multiply(vector, n));
        time_indexing(ind_m, ind_n) = timeit(@() f_indexing(vector, n));
    end
end
```

The **results** are plotted in the following two figures, **using `repmat` as reference**:

```
figure
imagesc(time_multiply./time_repmat)
set(gca, 'xtick',1:2:numel(N), 'xticklabels',N(1:2:end))
set(gca, 'ytick',1:2:numel(M), 'yticklabels',M(1:2:end))
title('Time of multiply / time of repmat')
axis image
colorbar

figure
imagesc(time_indexing./time_repmat)
set(gca, 'xtick',1:2:numel(N), 'xticklabels',N(1:2:end))
set(gca, 'ytick',1:2:numel(M), 'yticklabels',M(1:2:end))
title('Time of indexing / time of repmat')
axis image
colorbar
```

[image]
[image]

Perhaps a better comparison is to indicate, for each tested vector size and repetition factor, **which of the three approaches is the fastest**:

```
figure
times = cat(3, time_repmat, time_multiply, time_indexing);
[~, fastest] = min(times, [], 3);
imagesc(fastest)
set(gca, 'xtick',1:2:numel(N), 'xticklabels',N(1:2:end))
set(gca, 'ytick',1:2:numel(M), 'yticklabels',M(1:2:end))
title('1: repmat is fastest; 2: multiply is; 3: indexing is')    
axis image
colorbar
```

[image]

Some **conclusions** can be drawn from the figures:

- The multiply-based approach is always slower than `repmat`
- The indexing-based approach is similar to `repmat`. It tends to be faster for large values of vector size or repetition factor, and slower for small values.

Comment: I think I got the first two plots, but the third one .. couldn't interpret that one. I guess I am used to those line plots climbing up and down :)

Comment: @Divakar The third one tells which of the methods is fastest. It just contains 1, 2 or 3 for each (size, repetition factor)-bin

Answer (score 2):

Either method is correct if they provide you with the desired output.

However, depending on how you declare your vector you may get incorrect results with `repmat` that will be spotted if you use `ones`. For instance take this example

```
>> v = 1:10;
>> m = v * ones(1, n)
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
>> m = repmat(v, 1, n)
m =

  Columns 1 through 22

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10     1     2

  Columns 23 through 44

     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10     1     2     3     4

  Columns 45 through 50

     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

`ones` provides an error to let you know you aren't doing the right thing but `repmat` doesn't. Whilst this example works correctly with both `repmat` and `ones`

```
>> v = (1:10).';
>> m = v * ones(1, n)
m =

     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
     6     6     6     6     6
     7     7     7     7     7
     8     8     8     8     8
     9     9     9     9     9
    10    10    10    10    10
>> m = repmat(v, 1, n)
m =

     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
     6     6     6     6     6
     7     7     7     7     7
     8     8     8     8     8
     9     9     9     9     9
    10    10    10    10    10
```

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but `repmat` is a more general solution for multi-dimensional matrix copying and is thus bound to be slower than an other solution. The specific 'homemade' solution of multiplying two vectors is possibly faster. It is probably even faster to do selecting instead of multiplying, i.e. `vector(:,ones(n,1))` instead of `vector*ones(1,n)`.

EDIT:
Type  `open repmat` in your Command Window. As you can see, it is not a built-in function. You can see that it also makes use of `ones` (selecting) to copy matrices. However, since it is a more general solution (for scalars and multi-dimensional matrices and copies in multiple directions), you will find unnecessary `if` statements and other unnecessary code, effectively slowing things down.

EDIT:
Multiplying vectors with `ones` becomes slower for very large vectors. The unequivocal winner is using `ones` with selection, i.e. `vector(:,ones(n,1))` (which should always be faster than `repmat` since it uses the same strategy).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this -

```
vector(:,ones(1,n))
```

But, if I have to choose, `repmat` would be the go-to approach for me, as it is made exactly for this purpose. Also, depending on how you are going to use this replicated array, you can just avoid creating it altogether with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) that does on-the-fly replication on its input arrays and some operation to be applied on the inputs. Here's a comparison on that - [`Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat) that shows `bsxfun` to be better than `repmat` in most cases.

### Benchmarking

For the sake of performance, let's test out these. Here's a benchmarking code to do so -

```
%// Inputs
vector = rand(1000,1);
n = 1000;

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for iter = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp(' ------- With REPMAT -------')
tic,
for iter = 1:200
    A = repmat(vector, 1, n);
end
toc, clear A

disp(' ------- With vector(:,ones(1,n)) -------')
tic,
for iter = 1:200
    A = vector(:,ones(1,n));
end
toc, clear A

disp(' ------- With vector * ones(1, n) -------')
tic,
for iter = 1:200
    A = vector * ones(1, n);
end
toc
```

Runtime results -

```
 ------- With REPMAT -------
Elapsed time is 1.241546 seconds.
 ------- With vector(:,ones(1,n)) -------
Elapsed time is 1.212566 seconds.
 ------- With vector * ones(1, n) -------
Elapsed time is 3.023552 seconds.
```

Comment: I was also doing some time tests. I'll post them soon