# Matlab Repeat Value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I this matrix:

```
A = [2 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2];
```

I need to change that matrix into:

```
B = [2 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2;
     2 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2;
     2 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2]
```

the output will be:

```
B =

 2     3     4     6     7     8     9     1     2
 2     3     4     6     7     8     9     1     2
 2     3     4     6     7     8     9     1     2
```

Thank you so much...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: create matrix whose rows are identical vector. Use repmat() or multiply by ones()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797649/matlab-create-matrix-whose-rows-are-identical-vector-use-repmat-or-multiply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`repmat`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [**`repelem`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) are used for repeating the copies of an array. For your case, you can use either of these as: `repmat(A,3,1)` or `repelem(A,3,1)`