# Simplification of a complex expression

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix, bsxfun

I have this complicated MATLAB expression that I would like to simplify, so that I can actually understand it.

```
g = repmat(log(p), [size(x, 1), 1])
    for i = 1:size(mu, 1)
        g(:, i) = g(:, i) - sum(log(sigma(i, :)));
        g(:, i) = g(:, i) - sum(bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, x, mu(i, :)).^2, 2*sigma(i, :).^2), 2);
    end

p=1x2
sigma=2x2
mu=2x2
x=30x2
```

Basically these `bsxfun` functions confuse me a lot. I would like to express it in the form of simple `for` loops.

I tried something like this:

```
[m,n] = size(x)
for i=1:m
        for j=1:n
            g(i,j)= log(p(j)) - sum(log(sigma(j))) - sum(data(i,j))... ;
        end
    end
```

Not quite sure how to continue from this point, mostly errors and wrong results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the code in the question could be used as a nice `bsxfun` and `permute` practice session to vectorize everything. I understand this is going the other way from what's asked in the question, but take it as an alternative solution.

Coming back, to actually vectorize everything, you need to extend dimensions with [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and continue on using `bsxfun`. The implementation would look like this -

```
%// Vectorize : "g(:, i) = g(:, i) - sum(log(sigma(i, :)))"
parte1 = bsxfun(@minus,g,sum(log(sigma),2).'); %//'

%// Vectorize : "bsxfun(@minus, x, mu(i, :)).^2"
parte2_1 = bsxfun(@minus,x,permute(mu,[3 2 1])).^2;

%// Vectorize : "bsxfun(@rdivide, ...*sigma(i, :).^2)"
parte2 = bsxfun(@rdivide,parte2_1,2*permute(sigma,[3 2 1]).^2);

%// Squeeze in dimensions of the BSXFUN extended array and subtract from parte1
g = parte1 - squeeze(sum(parte2,2));
```

Comment: Way to go sensei, vectorising his `bsxfun` even more!

Comment: @Adriaan That first line is meant for you :)

Comment: Thought as much. Tomorrow, I will master!

Comment: @Divakar mind = blown . Don't know why, but, I just accepted it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just explain you [`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), since interchanging that for a `for` loop is like interchanging your car for a bicycle in terms of speed.

A general introduction to `bsxfun` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat) in this fantastic answer by [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar).

Let's cut your program down piece by piece:

```
bsxfun(@minus, x, mu(i, :))
```

This simply tells you that each element in `x` is subtracted (`@minus`) from each element in `mu(i,:)`. Now this `bsxfun` is nested into another:

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, x, mu(i, :)).^2, 2*sigma(i, :).^2)
```

this `bsxfun` divides two things, hence the [`rdivide`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html). Each element obtained by the subtraction of the previously discussed `bsxfun` is divided by each element in `2*sigma(i,:).^2`, which is an array.

Finally, the `sum` of the entire thing is taken to obtain a single value. That's subtracted from the original entry for `g(:,i)` for every instance of `i`.

Note that it is very bad practise to [use `i` or `j` as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab), so one of the improvements of that code should be to change `i` to e.g. `ii` or `n` or whatever not built-in function; or, as Divakar was kind enough to show in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33070325/5211833), just get rid of all the loops entirely.