# Get vector indices before-and-after (window +/- 1) given indices

Tags: matlab, vector, find, octave, indices

What's the best Matlab/Octave idiom, given `idx` a vector of indices, to get the sorted vector of `idx +/-1` ?

I have an n x 7 data matrix, column 3 is an integer label, and I'm interested in viewing the neighborhood of discontinuities on it.
Hence I get the corresponding indices:

```
idx = find(diff(data(:,3)) > 0)

5297
6275
6832
...
20187
```

Then if I want to view that neighborhood +/- 1 on my column (e.g. on the (mx2) matrix `[idx-1; idx+1]`), I need to form the vector of `idx-1, idx+1` either concatenated in-order, or resorted.
I found some clunky ways of doing this, what's the proper way?
(I tried all of the [octave chapter on Rearranging Matrices](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Rearranging-Matrices.html#Rearranging-Matrices))

```
% WAY 1: this works, but is ugly - a needless O(n) sort
sort([idx-1; idx+1])

% horzcat,vertcat,vec only stack it vertically
horzcat([idx-1; idx+1])
horzcat([idx-1; idx+1]')

% WAY 2?
%One of vec([idx-1; idx+1]) or vec([idx-1; idx+1]') should work? but doesn't, they always stack columnwise
horzcat([idx-1; idx+1]')

ans =
Columns 1 through ...
5297    6275    6832 ...  20187    5299    6277    6834 ... 20189

% TRY 3...
reshape([idx-1; idx+1], [36,1]) doesn't work either
```

You would expect there are only two ways to unstack a 2xm matrix, but ...

Comment: (@Wolfie) Belatedly I found a near-duplicate, although the language used was different [Vectorizing computing array indexing/subsetting window in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001037/vectorizing-array-indexing-subsetting-in-matlab)

Comment: That's alright, it the accepted (only) answer shows how to use `bsxfun`, which is redundant with the implicit expansion now available (and shown below).

Comment: @Wolfie: best to post that over there. I don't mean to be littering SO with duplicates. And their answer is obsolete. Perhaps should close that into this.

Comment: You can't flag a question as duplicate of a newer question... and by redundant, I mean you don't *need* it in MATLAB R2016b+ or Octave, but you can still use it.

Comment: @Wolfie yes you can close towards newer. Since that question and its accepted answer are obsolete and not vectorized (and bsxfun is obscure), arguably we should close. Unless you want to repost this answer there, and note existing answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with implicit singleton expansion (R2016b or newer MATLAB, native to Octave)

```
idx = [2, 6, 9]; % some vector of integers
% Use reshape with [] to tell MATLAB "however many rows it takes"
neighbours = reshape( idx + [-1;1], [], 1 );

>> neighbours = [1; 3; 6; 8; 8; 10];
```

If you don't know whether `idx` is a row or column, you can be more robust by using

```
neighbours = reshape( idx(:)' + [-1,1], [], 1)
```

If you don't want to use implicit expansion (and again coping with either row or column `idx`), you can use reshape like so

```
neighbours = reshape( [idx(:)-1, idx(:)+1]', [], 1 )
```

---

Note: you may also want to wrap the whole thing in a call to `unique`. In my example, you get the index `8` twice, I'm not sure if this is desirable or not in your situation.

However, `unique` performs a sort (unless you use the `'stable'` flag but that can make it even slower), so you might as well use your original approach if you want to remove duplicates:

```
% Remove duplicates and sort the result using unique 
neighbours = unique( [idx-1, idx+1] );
```

Comment: `[idx-1, idx+1]' (:)` does it too

Comment: You can safely assume `idx` is a row vector (it's the result of the `find()` command)

Comment: `( idx(:)' + [-1; 1] )(:)` works, without needing to call `reshape()`

Comment: What kills me is why do all octave's matrix-manipulation functions `horzcat()/vertcat()/cat()` not work? Surely there are only two damn ways to unstack a 2D matrix... but they only do column-wise

Comment: You cannot assume the output of `find` is a row vector, `find([1;3;4;0])` returns a column vector as the input was a column vector. As mentioned in my other comment, you cannot use `(:)` in the same expression as a matrix creation in MATLAB, that is exclusive to Octave. `horzcat/vertcat/cat` all work in MATLAB and Octave, and the first two are equivalent like `[1, 2] == horzcat([1], [2])` and `[1; 2] == vertcat([1], [2])` so I'm not sure what you meant there.

Comment: I should have said You can safely assume idx is a **column** vector (it's the result of the `find()` command on column `data(:,3)`) . In my context it's guaranteed idx is a column vector. But yes your generalized approach is going further.

Comment: Right. In my case `find(diff(data(:,3)) > 0)` is guaranteed to give unique indices. Also it looks like `horzcat()/vertcat()/cat()` are for concatenating matrices into matrices, not into vectors. The octave chapter on Rearranging Matrices is not that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I finally found this octave matrix manipulation:

```
vec([idx-1, idx+1]')
ans =

5297
5299
6275
6277
6832
6834
...
20187
20189
```

---

Adapting Wolfie's solution into the shortest Octave-only code:

```
[idx-1, idx+1]' (:)  
( idx(:)' + [-1; 1] )(:)
```

`idx = ( find(diff(data(:,3)) > 0 )' + [-1; 1] )(:)` works as a one-liner

... and `[idx , data(idx,3)]` displays the indices and data, side-by-side

Comment: Note that I don't believe `vec` is a MATLAB function, it is exclusive to Octave. In Matlab, you would assign to a temp variable, then use `x(:)` instead of `vec(x)`... this approach works in Octave too

Comment: @Wolfie and `[idx-1, idx+1]' (:)` does this too

Comment: That also won't work in MATLAB, as you cannot index an array as you create it (which you're doing with `[numbers](:)`. Only Octave allows for this sort of instant indexing.

Comment: Whoa, is Octave better than Matlab in some ways?

Comment: So `( find(diff(data(:,3)) > 0 )' + [-1; 1] )(:)` works as a one-liner in Octave

Comment: I acknowledged your solution, and accepted your answer. Thanks. Was trying to refine your answer into the shortest octave syntax, also given can assume column vector in my context.

Comment: Ah I understand, glad I could help