# MATLAB Normal random numbers generation for array of means without loop

Tags: matlab, loops, random

```
mu=[1 2 3 4 5]';   
sigma=[1 1 1 1 1]';
N=100;    %Number of samples for each mu
R=normrnd(mu,sigma,?)
```

Using normrnd, is it possible to generate N samples for each mu value without a loop (such that R will be 5 by 100 matrix)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know normrnd.

With older randn, I would have used something like:

```
repmat(mu,N,1) + randn(N,length(mu))*diag(sigma)
```

**EDIT**

Ah, you want the transpose 5x100, it's

```
repmat(mu,1,N) + diag(sigma)*randn(length(mu),N)
```

Comment: That works.  If I may make a suggestion, consider using `bsxfun` instead of `repmat`: `bsxfun(@plus, mu, randn(N, numel(mu))*diag(sigma));` You can see a comprehensive survey in comparison of performance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat - Generally `bsxfun` is faster and more efficient than using the equivalent code with `repmat`.