# Find the row/column of all maximum values in each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want search indexes maximum value/s in each row. If row has more than one maximum, so I want to save both indexes.

For example:

```
X = [5 6 8
     1 2 3
     4 4 0];
```

And I need indexes

```
inds = [1 3
        2 3
        3 1
        3 2];
```

I wanted to use function `max` but this function only saves one index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max` to compute the max for each row and then compare the elements in each row to it's row-wise `max` using `bsxfun` and `eq`. Then you can find the row/column positions of these maxima. We use a transpose in there (`.'`) to ensure that we get the ordering of the output that you expect.

```
[c,r] = find(bsxfun(@eq, d, max(d, [], 2)).')
output = [r,c];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, would be to use `max` and `repmat`.
First you find the maximum of each row using

```
rowMaximum=max(X,[],2);
```

Then you replicate the maximum so that it has the same dimension as your input and compare it to the input

```
logicalMaximum=repmat(rowMaximum,1,size(X,2))==X;
```

And the last thing you wanna do is converting this logical array into your desired indexes

```
[columns,rows]=find(logicalMaximum);
result=[rows,columns];
```

Comment: It's worth noting the extreme speedup that `bsxfun` offers over `repmat` for `eq` shown in [this extensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29719681/670206)