# Applying bsxfun to function with multiple output arguments

Tags: matlab, function, bsxfun

Let us assume we have a function `myfunction` with two output arguments

```
function [ arg1, arg2 ] = myfunction( a, b )
arg1 = a*b;
arg2 = a+b;
end
```

I want to apply `myfunction` to vector `A` and `B`:

```
fun = @myfunction;
A = 1:10;
B = 1:17;
[C, D] = bsxfun(fun,A,B)
```

This gives an error. How can I use `bsxfun` with functions having multiple output arguments?

Comment: If you replace the `*` by `.*` then your function will be able to take `A` and `B` and produce your desired result. Since the inputs do not have different shapes, `bsxfun` will not do anything special.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `arrayfun` instead?

Comment: How could I use `arrayfun` to produce as many `m x n` matrices as the number of output arguments of `myfunction`?

Comment: Did you read the help for `arrayfun`? It seems to me that `[C, D] = arrayfun(fun,A,B)` would do what you want.

Comment: Also, after the edit of your question, A and B are no longer compatible. `bsxfun` would no longer work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bsxfun` generates the output from all combinations of orthogonal matrices / vectors. Therefore to make your example work for even one output you have to transpose one of the inputs:

```
output1 = bsxfun(@myfunction,A,B.');
```

But as [rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) commented, the problem with bsxfun is that it can return only one output. As [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) suggested in a comment you can instead use [`arrayfun`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). The difference is that for `arrayfun` you have to explicit generate all input combinations by expanding the input `1xN` and `1xM` vectors to `NxM` matrices:

For Matlab 2016b and later:

```
[output1, output2] = arrayfun(@myfunction,A.*ones(numel(B),1),B.'.*ones(1,numel(A)));
```

Matlab pre-2016b:

```
[output1, output2] = arrayfun(@myfunction,bsxfun(@times,A,ones(numel(B),1)),bsxfun(@times,B.',ones(1,numel(A))))
```

Instead of using bsxfun to expand the matrices you could also use [`repmat`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)- but that's generally [a bit slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat).

Btw., If you have a function with many outputs and can't be bothered with writing `[output1, output2, output3, ...] = ...` you can just save them in a cell:

```
outputs = cell(nargout(@myfunction),1);
[outputs{:}] = arrayfun(@myfunction,....);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, the `bsxfun` is only for [binary operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)

Comment: What do you mean by "binary" operations?  This wording is unclear to me.  I think you mean that `bsxfun` does not work for multiple outputs.  It only provides one output.

Comment: I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation. In what way is that unclear?